Total derivative of type expression
The article The Derivative of a Regular Type is its Type of One-Hole Contexts introduces a derivative of type expression. In particular, the following rule is defined there:
$$
\partial_x \left(F|_{y=S}\right) = (\partial_x F)|_{y=S} + (\partial_y F)|_{y=S} \times \partial_x S
$$
It would seem that this is a kind of regular formula for the total derivative of functions on numbers. But from what fundamentsl considerations does it arise for type expressions? Where does the sum sign come from?

Let's summarize the discussion with Naïm Favier.
The one-hole context model leads to rules for "differentiation" of sums and products of types and the "chain rule" (as well as rules for 0, 1, constant, and Id). These rules only describe how to work with regular types. The rule for computing the total derivative of a regular type is derived by induction from the previous ones.
But in some sources (e.g. here) one can find the formula $\partial_A Bag[A] = Bag[A]$, where the type Bag is an exponential:
$$
Bag[A] = Nat^A
$$
This may raise doubts about the correctness of deriving the total derivative of types only from the rules for sums and products of types.
With a single constructor $1 + A \times Bag[A] + Bag[A] \times Bag[A] \rightarrow Bag[A]$, this type is treated as finite-size tuples factored by the number of permutations of their elements:
$$
Bag[A] = \sum_{n=0} \frac{A^n}{n!}
$$
With this treatment, the one-hole context is indeed determined by an operator acting as $\partial_A Bag[A] = Bag[A]$. And the total derivative for this series can be derived by induction as before.
However, the treatment of the exponential type Bag as such a series is questionable. The factor $n!$ correctly determines the number of permutations only if all elements of the tuple are different. So $Set[A] = 2^A$ looks more appropriate here then $Bag$.
Nevertheless, these examples hint that it might be possible to find derivatives of exponential types using the concept of dependent types...

A one-hole context of shape $x$ in $F|_{y=S}$ can be located under a $y$ or not. If not, it's already a one-hole context of shape $x$ in $F$. If so, then it's a one-hole context of shape $y$ in $F$ paired with a one-hole context of shape $x$ in $S$. This page contains enlightening illustrations, although not for the rule you mention.

I understand how it works. I wonder how this particular formula could be derived from some fundamental reasons. There must be some constructive proof that this formula is correct.

What do you mean by "fundamental"? Is this a math question or a philosophy question? The proof sketch I gave can be directly translated to a constructive proof that performs induction on syntax trees.

When you talk about tree shapes, do you mean fixed points of polynomial type constructors? But formally, derivatives are defined for any type expression, not necessarily recursive. Including exponentials and their combinations... I don't see how to get a constructive proof from this sketch. Maybe this formula doesn't work when exponentials are present? I'm not sure...

What is your definition of the derivative? The paper defines it directly by induction on syntax, pulling these formulas out of thin air, so that doesn't help you. What I'm suggesting is to define the type of one-hole contexts in $F$ as a slight variation of the "normal" semantics of $F$ that keeps track of the "hole", and then prove that it's equivalent to the semantics of the derivative the paper defines. I'll try to sketch an Agda proof later.

And indeed this only concerns regular types, which are not closed under function types.

Thank you. I had feeling that the only basement of this rule is sum and product rules.
But I was confused by a statement $\partial_x (\mathbf{N}^x) = \mathbf{N} ^x$ found in some source.
I'm not sure if this is really correct…

I'm not sure it even makes sense. I don't know what a one-hole context of shape $x$ in $\mathbf{N}^x$ is.
